# How to suppress Post during kendo-upload

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am using Kendo-upload to upload the cert file and get the base64 string back. In this case I don't want to use it via the [saveUrl]="uploadSaveUrl"...rather I am using the (upload)="uploadEventHandler($event)".

Things are working fine except I guess the Kendo-upload does try to upload via the POST method as well even if I did not specify [saveUrl]. Is there a way to suppress this POST completely?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to? a POST is more secure than a GET

Comment: Even in upload I am doing a POST. As I said there should be a way to suppress the default [saveUrl] so that an error won't appear.

Comment: whats the value of `uploadSaveUrl`?

Comment: Did not set it at all. I tried a empty string as well. Whatever be the case you will see a post for http://localhost:4200/ as 404 error.

Comment: if you didn't set it, it wont ever work...

Comment: Please read above in the uploadEventHandler you can do anything in this case I do a angular http.post. That does work! I was just trying to suppress the default post.

Comment: but if `uploadSaveUrl` isnt set, it cant work unless it has a default value if it is blank

Comment: The post from uploadEventHandler does work. I don;t want uploadSaveUrl. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to prevent the upload event, after you have retrieved the required file data. This will result in removing the file from the list though.

Answer (score 0):

It seem there is an option now (maybe it existed all along) `[autoUpload]=false`

```
  <kendo-upload
    #myUpload="kendoUpload"
    [autoUpload]="false"
    [saveUrl]="uploadSaveUrl"
    [removeUrl]="uploadRemoveUrl">     
  </kendo-upload>
```

Also if there is no need for `Upload` button - it can be optionally removed

```
/deep/ .k-upload-selected {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

There is a github discussion customizing upload action button bar: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/692